# How to make 2 grid stand in same line?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to make these rating star same line with the word "Review" but it seems like it's stand in a middle of the line. How can I fix it?

Here is my project:

[image]

And this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

How can I do it?

Here is my code base:

```
<div className="container--user_display">
  <div className="container--user_card_top">
    <img
      className="image image--search_avatar"
      src={userObj.picture}
      alt="Avatar"
    />
    <h3 className="header header--user_card_name">
      {userObj.fullname}
    </h3>
  </div>
  <hr className="hr--dashboard_page_break" />
  <div className="container--user_card_bottom">
    {/* {canInvite && <InviteButton userObj={userObj} />} */}
    <div className="user_rating_data">Skillsets: {skillElement}</div>
    <h4 className="user_rating_data">Reviews:
    {
        userObj.Skills.length > 0 ?
        <div className="hello">
            <Rating value={totalRating} precision={0.5} readOnly max={5} className="user_rating_found" />
            <p className="text text--user_rating user_rating_found"><span>{totalRating}</span>/5</p>
        </div>
        : <div>{skillsetStr}</div>
    }
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS file:

```
.container--user_display {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  row-gap: 16px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--bg-white);
  box-shadow: var(--shadow-mid);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.container--user_card_top {
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 4px;
  row-gap: 4px;
}

.container--user_card_bottom {
  width: 100%;

  .user_rating_data {
    word-break: break-all;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    width: 100%;
  }

}

.svg--user_card_icon {
  width: 58px;
  height: 62px;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}


.image--search_avatar {
  height: 64px;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url("/avatar_icon_backup.png") no-repeat;
}
```

How can I achieve this look using scss?

Thank you for helping me out. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

From your HTML, you're using a `div` element to wrap the ratings.

A `div` element's `display` property is defaulted to `block`. Which means it should take up the whole width of it's parent.

You can either set the `display` property to `inline-block` or use a `span` element which has that `display` value as its default